# insolation level read_committed_snapshot hace lecturas sucias

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente duda : Si tengo el sql server configurado con el esquema insolation level   read_committed_snapshot  de base de datos   cdo se hace varios selects en una primera sesion y en luego otra sesion se habre un transaccion , los select de la primera sesion son lecturas sucias o obtiene la ultima version ?

Se logra lo mismo que nolock.para ese caso?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Se obtiene la última versión, tal como lo indica el nombre. Puedes leer más acerca de eso en [la documentación de MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server). Dejo un extracto.

> **Extensiones del nivel de aislamiento de instantáneas**
>
> SQL Server 2005 presentaba extensiones a los niveles de aislamiento SQL-92 con la introducción del nivel de aislamiento SNAPSHOT y una implementación adicional de READ COMMITTED. El nivel de aislamiento READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT puede reemplazar de forma transparente a READ COMMITTED en todas las transacciones.
>
> - El aislamiento SNAPSHOT especifica que los datos leídos en una transacción nunca reflejarán los cambios que otras transacciones simultáneas hayan realizado. Cuando una transacción comienza, utiliza las versiones de filas de datos que existen. No existen bloqueos en los datos cuando se leen, de modo que las transacciones SNAPSHOT no impiden que otras transacciones escriban datos. Las transacciones que escriben datos no impiden que las transacciones de instantáneas los lean. Para utilizar la opción de base de datos ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION, deberá habilitar el aislamiento de instantáneas.
> - Cuando el aislamiento de instantáneas está habilitado en una base de datos, la opción de base de datos READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT determina el comportamiento del nivel de aislamiento predeterminado READ COMMITTED. Si no especifica explícitamente READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON, READ COMMITTED se aplica a todas las transacciones implícitas. Esto produce el mismo comportamiento que se si establece READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF (el valor predeterminado). Cuando READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF está activo, el motor de base de datos utiliza bloqueos compartidos para exigir el nivel de aislamiento predeterminado. Si establece la opción de base de datos READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT en ON, el motor de base de datos utiliza la versión de fila y el aislamiento de instantáneas como valor predeterminado, en lugar de utilizar bloqueos para proteger los datos.

Comment: graccias por responder Luis. Entonces  el dato obtenido  del select  ,es  la ultima  version no es sucia ,  es la version del   dato  que se esta actualizando en el update  de  la transaccion

Comment: Exacto. Toma la última versión sin bloquear a quien pudiera intentar actualizar los datos.

Comment: gracias Luis. No puedo agregar voto